# Sum of consecutive odd numbers and cubic numbers.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

> **Proposition:** Show that by suitably adding positive consecutive odd numbers, cubic numbers are obtained.

I have gotten a proof of this proposition, but I don't want to give it yet because I suspect someone has a shorter and more elegant proof than mine.
As a reliable sample that I have a proof, I propose to find the cubic number that is obtained by adding consecutive greater odd numbers to the number 16,257. A posteriori I will comment on my proof. Thank you for your attention to this problem.

Comment: Do you mean the sum is square?  $1=1, 1+3=4, 1+3+5=9$  The sum of all the odd numbers up to $16257$ is $(\frac 12(16257-1))^2$  You should show your proof so we can compare ours.  It is not even clear what your proposition is.

Comment: $1=1$, $3+5=8$, $7+9+11=27$, $13+15+17+19=64$ etc. Is this what you are talking about?

Comment: My English is really short, however I'm totally surprised how you could change my question in so different way! By the way, why did Keith understand my question exactly? A really mystery for me, sorry.

Comment: I Think I lost 3 points arbitrarily. Again I wonder: Why does Keith Backman understand perfectly my question? He gives the exact answer to my question and also generalizes it.  ''Adding suitably consecutive odd numbers''. Yes, suitable as you can't  adding, for instance, 9+11+13. ''Cubic numbers are obtained'' Yes! Whenever you sum adequately consecutive odd numbers. I'm sure that MATHEMATICS is managed by impartial moderators, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not just cubes, but any integral power of a positive integer can be written as the sum of consecutive odd integers. Moreover, $n^k$ can always be written as the sum of exactly $n$ odd integers, viz: $$\sum_{i=\frac{n^{k-1}-n}{2}+1}^{\frac{n^{k-1}+n}{2}}(2i-1)=n^k$$

**Added:** FWIW, using the above formula and the starting point $16257$ given by OP, one finds that $n=128$ and the $128$ odd numbers beginning with $16257$ sum to $128^3$

Comment: Thank you so much Keith. I read the problem at another site (not yet solved) just for the cubic case. Essentially I did realize  that  $1=1^3, \, 3+5=2^3, \,7+9+11=3^3,$ and so on. I found formulae for the first and last term: $k=n(n-1)+1, \qquad K=n(n+1)-1$, This solve the problem. It would be interesting if you give some hints to solve the general case you have above written. I sincerely appreciate your attention. BTW, I'm a Mechanical Engineer.

Comment: The summation of odd integers is an arithmetic series, so the sum equals the number of terms times their average value. The summation limits are formulated such that there are $n$ terms with an average value of $n^{k-1}$; $\ n\cdot n^{k-1}=n^k$

Comment: Sorry, $n$ is the number of terms in the sequence of odd numbers. For instance $n=17, \qquad k=17(17-1)+1=273; \qquad  K=17(17+1)-1=305.$ So, $273+275+\cdots+305=(273+305)x(17/2)=17^3.$

Comment: Crystal Keith, thanks again.